# VUE JS - Some of my methods are being called without me calling them

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, indexeddb

I'm having an annoying issue with Vue JS >.< My methods are being called without my approval. I basically have a button that execute a method, but this `method` execute when other methods are executed, making it very annoying...

Here is my form

```html
              <form class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 pr-xl-0 pr-lg-0 pr-md-0  m-b-30">
                  <div class="product-slider">
                    <img class="d-block" :src="image" alt="First slide" width="285" height="313">
                    Image URL <input type="text" @focusout="showPicture" id="imageLink">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 pl-xl-0 pl-lg-0 pl-md-0 border-left m-b-30">
                  <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
                      <h2 class="mb-3">
                        <input type="text" value="Product Name" minlength="4" id="name" required/>
                      </h2>
                      <h3 class="mb-0 text-primary">$<input type="number" value="1.00" step="0.01" id="price" required></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-size border-bottom">
                      <h4>Provider</h4>
                      <input type="text" value="Pro Inc." minlength="3" id="provider" required>
                      <div class="product-qty">
                        <h4>Quantity</h4>
                        <div class="quantity">
                          <input type="number" value="1" id="quantity" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-description">
                      <h4 class="mb-1">Description</h4>
                      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" minlength="50" id="description" required>Sample Text</textarea>
                      <button :onclick="addProduct()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Add to inventory</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

`and here is my full script`

```js
<script>
const DB_NAME = 'DBInventory';
const DB_VERSION = 1;
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      db:null,
      ready:false,
      addDisabled:false,
      image: "https://i.imgur.com/O9oZoje.png",
    };
  },
  async created() {
    this.db = await this.getDb();
    this.ready = true;
  },
  methods: {
    showPicture() {
      let link = document.getElementById("imageLink").value;
      if(link !== "")
        this.image = link;
    },
    async getDb() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let request = window.indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);

        request.onerror = e => {
          console.log('Error opening db', e);
          reject('Error');
        };

        request.onsuccess = e => {
          resolve(e.target.result);
        };

        request.onupgradeneeded = e => {
          console.log('onupgradeneeded');
          let db = e.target.result;
          let objectStore = db.createObjectStore("products", { autoIncrement: true, keyPath:'id' });
          console.log(objectStore);
        };
      });
    },
    async addProduct() {
      this.addDisabled = true;
      let product = {
        name: document.getElementById("name").value,
        provider: document.getElementById("provider").value,
        price: document.getElementById("price").value,
        quantity: document.getElementById("quantity").value,
        description: document.getElementById("description").value,
        image: document.getElementById("imageLink").value,
      };
      console.log('about to add '+JSON.stringify(product));
      await this.addProductToDb(product);
      this.addDisabled = false;
    },
    async addProductToDb(product) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //delete me
        console.log(reject);
        let trans = this.db.transaction(['products'],'readwrite');
        trans.oncomplete = e => {
          //delete me
          console.log(e);
          resolve();
        };
        let store = trans.objectStore('products');
        store.add(product);
      });
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

One of my method execute when you are not focused on the image input field. It works, but also execute the addProduct(), which push my item to my indexDB, something that I want to happen only when I press the button "Add to inventory".

This is very confusing and I'm kinda a noob on Vue JS ^^' (I use Vue 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the function to be autoexecuted, you need to provide the onclick method with the function declaration. Try the code below. I don't use Vue, but it works in React. Javascript anyway.

`:onclick="() => addProduct()"`

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong syntax
`:onclick="addProduct()"`

`:onclick` should be `@click` or `v-on:click`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for click event in vue
full syntax

```
<a v-on:click="addProduct"></a>
```

shorthand syntax

```
<a @click="addProduct"></a>
```

Then call method addProduct

```
addProduct: function () {
      ...
    }
```